# nHibernate unable to cast Boolean to String

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have the following query:

```
var query = from item in Session.Query<FactuurItem>()
    where item.EnergieType == etype
    && (item.DienstType == null || item.DienstType == DienstType.Onbekend || item.DienstType == dtype)
    && item.IsActive == true
    orderby item.Naam
    select item;
```

Which is converted to the following SQL:

```
select * from [FactuurItem] factuurite0_ 
where 
    factuurite0_.EnergieType=? 
    and (factuurite0_.DienstType is null or factuurite0_.DienstType=? or factuurite0_.DienstType=?) 
    and case when factuurite0_.IsActive=1 then 'true' else 'false' end=case when ?='true' then 'true' else 'false' end 
order by factuurite0_.Naam asc
```

Which results in the Exception:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'."}
```

Now for my question: why??

The original query looks ok to me. The SQL, however, does not. Where do the two case-statements originate from? Apparently it tries to convert the property IsActive to a string in SQL, which it fails to do.

**EDIT**

Ok, found the solution. Nothing wrong with mapping etc., just with how the LINQ query is translated to SQL. In particular, how this line is translated:

```
&& item.IsActive == true
```

Somehow, this gets translated into the complex CASE-statement which ultimately results in the exception message. However, the `== true`-part isn't really necessary. By removing it, the translator no longer gets confused and provides the proper SQL:

```
factuurite0_.IsActive=1
```

No more CASE-statement and no more exception.

Comment: Please show us the mapping for FactuurItem. The mapping defines which SQL type each field will be mapped to.

Comment: Since you have found a solution, you can answer your own question by providing an answer in the box below. Subsequentially, you can accept it by clicking the tick icon (but not right away).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution. Nothing wrong with mapping etc., just with how the LINQ query is translated to SQL. In particular, how this line is translated:

```
&& item.IsActive == true
```

Somehow, this gets translated into the complex CASE-statement which ultimately results in the exception message. However, the `== true`-part isn't really necessary. By removing it, the translator no longer gets confused and provides the proper SQL:

```
factuurite0_.IsActive=1
```

No more CASE-statement and no more exception.

Answer (score 1):

Using Log4Net at the debug level?  In some version of Hibernate and Log4Net there is an incompatibility when turn on logging at the DEBUG level.  All you get is this error about 'unable to execute sql cannot cast boolean to string'.  Try turning up your logging level to INFO and the problem should go away.